# How to patch pod's container spec to start container with my version of exec, via kubernetes admission controller?

Tags: kubernetes

I am writing an admission controller, which is responsible for starting all the containers with my version of `exec` say `myexec`.

I know, I can modify `command` in pod's container spec, to prefix with `myexec`.

But I am stuck in the case when there is no `command` in pod's container spec. In those cases, as per my understanding, I have to find which the entrypoint command/script of the image that container is going to load. And I need to set `command` as `myexec entrypoint.sh`.

That seems tricky and expensive since I have to inspect the image, find entrypoint, all inside the admission controller.

What i want to mention is that kubernetes already pulling image (in case if image was already pulled in previously or loaded explicitly beforehand in clusters) and having manifest on their nodes, it might be sending those entrypoint information as container config, but i am not aware how to capture those during admission.

So I am seeking some hint, trick or way that I am not aware of to achieve my goal.

PS: I can't change image configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is this project [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) that allows you to query any container registy for metadata like e.g. entrypoint and command.

You can use skopeo cmd tool to test it.

Follow [this install instructions](https://github.com/containers/skopeo/blob/master/install.md) to install it.

Now try the following:

```
$ skopeo inspect --config  docker://nginx:latest
```

What you probably saw is a lot of output. We don't need most of it for our usecase.
What we are interested in is under `.config`. I used `jq` to query it. Have a look:

```
$ skopeo inspect --config  docker://nginx:latest | jq ".config"
{
  "ExposedPorts": {
    "80/tcp": {}
  },
  "Env": [
    "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
    "NGINX_VERSION=1.19.5",
    "NJS_VERSION=0.4.4",
    "PKG_RELEASE=1~buster"
  ],
  "Entrypoint": [
    "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
  ],
  "Cmd": [
    "nginx",
    "-g",
    "daemon off;"
  ],
  "Labels": {
    "maintainer": "NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"
  },
  "StopSignal": "SIGQUIT"
}
```

Notice the fields: `Entrypoint` and `Cmd`. I belive this is what you are looking for. And all of it is done without pulling any images. How cool is that?

You could probably take the source code (it's under apache licence so feel free to modify it), make rest service out of it and have admission controller to query it for the information about endpoints/cmds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as you see, the question already mentioned "That seems tricky and expensive since I have to inspect the image, find entrypoint, all inside the admission controller." and even if i host rest service, that be slow down admission a bit. What i want to mention is that kubernetes already pulling image and having manifest on their nodes, it might be sending those entrypoints, but i am not aware how to capture those.

Comment: From docs: "An admission controller is a piece of code that intercepts requests to the Kubernetes API server prior to persistence of the object[...]". This means that admission runs before object gis created, before scheduler is notified about the object, and way before pod gets assigned to a node and kubelet starts pulling image.

Comment: "kubernetes already pulling image and having manifest on their nodes" - You can't just patch a pod object in flight once it's created. Pods are immutable. If you want to change sth in pod spec you need to delete it and create a new one. Also, its not pulling anything before it gets assigned to a node. Kubelet it pulling images to node but only after its has been told to do so by the scheduler.

Comment: Images are pulled once pod is created. But there are cases, when image is already loaded. Can't i just get information from the pulled image database about its entrypoint, when it is has been already pulled?

Comment: Images are pulled by kubelet once pod gets assigned its node to run on (typically by scheduler). In case an image is already pulled, this image lives on specific node so you could go to this node and check this image, but k8s does not provide any api to inspect iamges on the nodes so you would need to figure it out by yourself. This approach creates some problems. What is you have a pod with image with tag `:latest`? Its documented that k8s will always force pull all new images when image has `latest` tag. Now what if you inspect this image localy but the image in repository is different?

Comment: "kubernetes already pulling image and having manifest on their nodes, it might be sending those entrypoint information as container config, but i am not aware how to capture those during admission" - you can't becasue its not pulling anything before pod object is created and this is not going to happen before admission. admission is the very first thing that happens prior to persistence of the object. Only after its persisted apiserver will notify other contollers about its existence but this is already too late to alter pod spec due to pods immutability.

Comment: I totally agree with you that images are not pulled anything before admission is done. But in my case, all possible images are always loaded in clusters at time of cluster creation itself, and imagePullPolicy is marked "Never". And certainly "latest" tags are never used in my usecase. If we don't have solution today, k8s should bring this as a feature.

Comment: If you belive this is a great feature that would positively impact other users then feel free to open feature request on kubernetes github repo.